# Cast to multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, casting

I would like to know if it is possible to cast an object to multiple classes that it inherits from without knowing its initial type. For example, suppose I have the following structs:

```
struct A {
    int a;
};

struct B {
    int b;
};

struct C {
    int c;
};

struct D {
    int d;
};

struct Z : A, B, C, D {};
```

And I add instances of Z to a vector.

```
vector<A *> v;
Z *zed = new Z();
v.push_back(zed);
```

Now suppose that I know that the first element in the vector inherits from A and B and I would like to cast it to A and B.

```
struct Tmp : A, B {};
Tmp *tmp = static_cast<Tmp *>(v[0]);
tmp->b = 6;
cout << zed->b << endl;
```

However, doing this causes issues. Mainly if Z was instead defined as `struct Z : A, C, D, B {};` then `cout << zed->b << endl;` would print 0 and not 6. How would you get around this?

I understand that doing this is potentially unsafe and probably poor design, however, i'm still interested in knowing if it's possible.

Comment: You can do it, but only if you introduce a level of hierarchy.  ie.  Introduce a `struct AB : A, B` that both `Z` and `Tmp` inherit from.  But as you suggested, this is really poor design.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dynamic_cast` to go "across" the inheritance hierarchy. But there needs to be at least one virtual function in the "from" type, and you can't cast from a virtual or multiply-inherited base.

```
struct A {
    int a;
    virtual ~A() {}
};

struct Z : A, B, C, D {};
vector<A *> v;
Z *zed = new Z();
v.push_back(zed);

B *tmp = dynamic_cast<B *>(v[0]);
```

This uses runtime type inspection and yields `nullptr` if `v[0]` wasn't derived from `B` after all.

As for `struct Tmp`, according to the language it's not related to `Z` at all despite having common bases. What if `Tmp` also declared its own members? If you want access to the `B` and `C` subobjects regardless of how they were inherited, get references using two separate `dynamic_cast` operations.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `A` and `B` more than once there (both to cast and to create the `Tmp` struct. I'd suggest you to give an useful name to `struct X : A, B {...}` and define `Z` as: `struct Z : X, C, D {}`.

Then the cast becomes:

```
X* tmp = static_cast<X*>(v[0]);
tmp->b = 6;
std::cout << zed->b << std::endl;
```